# Unit Testing on Webview's using JUnit

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, webview

I have some troubles making this unit test work properly and I can't seem to figure it out. If you can please lend a hand in reviewing the below code and error and see if it makes sense to you. I know this is something easy, I just can't seem to get it to work properly.

I have a issue with (mError cannot be resolved to a variable). What am I doing wrong, I have created the variable in my MockWebViewClient class. Now I got the test to still run when I comment out the lines of code where mError is used.

However now, when running my test I get "junit.framework.AssertionFailedError" on the following line of code below

```
assertTrue(!(mWeb.getProgress() < 100));
```

Thanks in advance.

### WebviewTest.java

```
private static final String VALID_URL = "http://www.google.com";
private static final String INVALID_URL = "http://invalid.url.doesnotexist987.com";
private static final long TIMEOUT = 5000; 
private Enlighten_Webview_Main mActivity;
private WebView mWeb;
private WebViewClient mMockWebViewClient;

// Rest of my code....

public final void testLoadValidUrl() {
        assertLoadUrl(VALID_URL);
        assertFalse(mMockWebViewClient, mError);
    }

    public final void testLoadInvalidUrl() {
        assertLoadUrl(INVALID_URL);
        assertTrue(mMockWebViewClient.mError);
    }

    private void assertLoadUrl(String url) {
        mWeb.loadUrl(url);
        sleep();

            //Added to hopefully let webview load all the way
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

        assertTrue(!(mWeb.getProgress() < 100));            
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(TIMEOUT);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            fail("Unexpected timeout");
        }
    }
    public class MockWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        boolean mError;

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            mError = true;
        }
    }
```

### EDIT

I Fixed the issue by switching my `mMockWebViewClient` variable to the correct type, which is `MockWebViewClient`. Since the `MockWebViewClient` class contains the `mError` boolean that i needed in `testLoadValidUrl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable "mError" is not defined in your `testLoadValidUrl` method, probably a typo. There is a comma "," when you probably meant a period "." for member access.

I.e. change

```
public final void testLoadValidUrl() {
    assertLoadUrl(VALID_URL);
    assertFalse(mMockWebViewClient, mError);
}
```

to

```
public final void testLoadValidUrl() {
    assertLoadUrl(VALID_URL);
    assertFalse(mMockWebViewClient.mError);
}
```

Comment: When changing that i now get the following error "mError cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Your variable "mMockWebViewClient" is a "WebViewClient" reference, not a "MockWebViewClient" reference.  Cast it to "MockWebViewClient" then access the member.  Make sure that the variable "mMockWebViewClient" is assigned an actual "MockWebViewClient" instance.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue simply by changing "private WebViewClient mMockWebViewClient;" to "private MockWebViewClient mMockWebViewClient;"  Thank you rgettman